# Trouble Trying to Apply Specific View to UINavigationController as Root

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an app where I have a primary view that presents three buttons.  Depending upon which button is clicked, I will send the user to a new view.

As you can see in the screenshot below I have the storyboard setup to handle the buttons and their redirects.

[image: Main Storyboard]

I am attempting to programmatically add the `UINavigationController` to the home screen with the three buttons.  Here is my attempt thus far:

On `myAppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.    
    UINavigationController *home = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

    myViewController  *homeView = [[myViewController alloc]init];
    [home setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeView, nil]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:home];

    return YES;    
}
```

On `myViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Home"];

    //create UIBarButtonItem

    UIBarButtonItem *goToAddBoardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"+ Add" style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:self action:@selector(AddBoardTranisition)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:goToAddBoardButton];



}

- (void) AddBoardTranisition
{
    AddBoard *addBoardView = [[AddBoard alloc]init];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:addBoardView animated:YES];

}
```

At this point you may see that I am transitioning to another view entirely when the user clicks the `+ Add` button in the upper right.  This works for sending the user to a new Class file, but what I need is a bit different.

First of all, I would like to present the `home` view with the 3 buttons.  Then after they click on the button they are sent to a new view class which contains it’s own navigation controller.  Thank you for your attention to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed your root view controller (the one associated with what you call your Main View) in a navigation controller.  In Interface Builder ensure that your main view controller is selected, then click Editor in Xcode menu, click Embed in..., and select Navigation Controller.  Then you can delete the lines of code from your applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Comment: @Presto Glad I could help.  Good luck with your app!